# How to wait for an fadeout function to end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I would like to change a value when a fadeOut function is over.

I have the following function:

```
    const fadeOut = (duration: number = 300) => {
        Animated.timing(
            opacity,
            {
                toValue: 0,
                duration,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }
        ).start();
    }
```

And I call it this way:

```
    const fadeOutScreen = () => {
        fadeOut(1000);

        // The value would be true when the fadeOut is over
        setHide(true);
    }
```

But the value is changed before the operation ends.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it async:

> [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#working-with-animations) are the docs

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwIIDtQEMYFMAmBfOAMyghDgHIot0BjGAWhU2ADctyBuAWAChecsNADboqcGhBQBneBDC1gMAJ4AuOOhRKANHClYYACWAC1Gpdz48J0+IXQCA8gFd4AXjgAKHE6jNJalCcQACMsKDh3AGYABmiASgiAPjgULAB3OAAFEhBgPQAeYIgIIWoURI8qKRK2JMReODhUDGwcADoYUGAUAHMPBsa4OQVlLQHGhHHBmAgANXQhJyw1aLGeQcHvX07JNY3Gpz0AOWY2ABEoVjC1GCglvcG8Abi2mVEYDw8EQm68gAtcHgEq5klUalgPD80FIATg4nELECLLxrDIiPYsM4YABlGhULAoCLqKRKFA0TzA5KTdbiSRoqH-XBE9BpdCKdGOFweACMsXiFkawEIngZMNwCT0hmMENuSwRAywQj09RpjQA9Gr1GgQH5CaypHButgoHcwK0Bk8eHgOEA)

```ts
const fadeOut = (duration: number = 300) => new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
  Animated.timing(
    opacity,
    {
      toValue: 0,
      duration,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }
  ).start(({finished}) => resolve(finished));
});

const fadeOutScreen = async () => {
  const finished = await fadeOut(1000);
  if (finished) setHide(true);
  else {
    // animation was interrupted
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation runs asynchronously, but the `fadeOutScreen` function will continue to execute synchronously after the animation is started.

`Animated.start()`, however, takes a callback that is called once the animation is finished, so you can do it like this:

```js
const fadeOut = (duration: number = 300, cb?: (boolean) => void) => {
    Animated.timing(
        opacity,
        {
            toValue: 0,
            duration,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }
    ).start(
      //vvvvvvvv--- This tells whether the animation has finished or stopped
      ({finished}) => cb?.(finished)
      //                ^^--- Only call callback if present (new syntax)
    );
}
```

```js
const fadeOutScreen = () => {
    fadeOut(
        1000, 
        finished => {
            if(finished)
                setHide(true);
        }
    );
}
```